# How can I create multiple versions of the same request with OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, swagger-codegen

I use maven Swagger Codegen V3 plugin to generate API from a yaml file.
I want to generate different versions of a rest request which has the same path but different body types.

I use this YAML code to generate it.

```
content:
    application/json;version=1.0.0:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object1'
    application/json;version=2.0.0:
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object2'
```

And I get the following result:

```
@Consumes({ "application/json;version=1.0.0", "application/json;version=2.0.0" })
...
public void method(Object1 body);

@Consumes({ "application/json;version=1.0.0", "application/json;version=2.0.0" })
...
public void method(Object2 body);
```

But the result I need is like below.

```
@Consumes({ "application/json;version=1.0.0" })
...
public void method(Object1 body);

@Consumes({ "application/json;version=2.0.0" })
...
public void method(Object2 body);
```

I use the consumes parameter for the versioning. So is there a way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a limitation Swagger Codegen v3 does not support multiple payload at the moment. The [Petstore OpenAPI document](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen-generators/blob/master/src/test/resources/3_0_0/petstore.yaml#L732-L741) has endpoints that can send either JSON or XML payload but the output (auto-generated code) only supports JSON at the moment.